# How to apply weights in neural network?

Tags: c#, neural-network

I am attempting to learn how to implement neural networks. The one main thing I can't seem to find anywhere is how to apply and store the weights. I got this to work in a simple [2 Input, 4 Output] Network by manually doing all of the multiplication for each output. But now I have 4 Input, 4 Hidden in 2 Layers, and 4 Outputs and am storing them in a 4x4x2 Array. I can't seem to grasp how to apply this using for loops. The current code below shows what I currently have and the parts commented as neural network are what I am currently trying to figure out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//Import SFML
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.System;
using SFML.Window;
namespace GeneticAlgorithims
{
    class Program
    {
        //Neural Network Variables
        public static int Inputs = 4;
        public static int Outputs = 4;
        public static int Hiddens = 2;
        //End Variables
        public static Random rand = new Random();
        public static List<Organism> organisms = new List<Organism>();
        public static RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800,600), "Neural Networks", Styles.Default, new ContextSettings(512, 512, 16));
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Generate();
            while(window.IsOpen)
            {
                window.DispatchEvents();
                Update();
                window.Clear(Color.Cyan);
                Draw();
                window.Display();
            }
        }

        static void Generate()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
                organisms.Add(new Organism(new Vector2f(rand.Next(0, (int)window.Size.X), rand.Next(0, (int)window.Size.Y)), new Matrix(new double[Inputs, Inputs, Hiddens])));
            }

            foreach (Organism organism in organisms)
            {
                organism.color = new Color((byte)rand.Next(0, 255),(byte)rand.Next(0, 255),(byte)rand.Next(0, 255));
                organism.rotation = rand.Next(1, 360);
            }
        }

        static void Update()
        {
            //Image map = window.Capture();
            foreach(Organism organism in organisms)
            {
                //Get Near Organism
                Organism near = new Organism();
                foreach (Organism check in organisms)
                {
                    if (check != organism)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(check.position.X - organism.position.X) < 128)
                        {
                            if (Math.Abs(check.position.Y - organism.position.Y) < 128)
                            {
                                near = check;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Begin Neural Network
                int CurrentColor = near.color.R;
                float DistanceX = (near.position != null) ? Math.Abs(near.position.X - organism.position.X) : 0;
                float DistanceY = (near.position != null) ? Math.Abs(near.position.Y - organism.position.Y) : 0;
                float Health = organism.Health;
                Console.WriteLine(CurrentColor);
                for (int A = 0; A < Inputs; A++)
                {
                    for (int B = 0; B < Outputs; B += 4)
                    {
                        for (int C = 0; C < Hiddens; C++)
                        {
                            organism.rotation += 
                        } 
                    } 
                }
                    //End Neural Network
                    organism.Age++;
                organism.position.X += organism.Speed * (float)Math.Cos(organism.rotation * 0.0174f);
                organism.position.Y += organism.Speed * (float)Math.Sin(organism.rotation * 0.0174f);

                float X = organism.position.X;
                float Y = organism.position.Y;
                if (organism.position.X > window.Size.X) organism.position.X = 0;
                if (organism.position.X < 0) organism.position.X = window.Size.X;
                if (organism.position.Y > window.Size.Y) organism.position.Y = 0;
                if (organism.position.Y < 0) organism.position.Y = window.Size.Y;

                if(organism.Age % 2500 == 0)
                {
                    Organism newOrganism = new Organism(organism.position, organism.brain);
                    newOrganism.rotation = rand.Next(0, 360);
                    newOrganism.color = organism.color;
                    //organisms.Add(newOrganism);
                    //return;
                }
                if (organism.Age > 3000)
                {
                    //organisms.Remove(organism);
                    //return;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Draw()
        {
            Sprite bufferSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("img.png"));
            foreach (Organism organism in organisms)
            {

                Vertex[] line = new Vertex[2];
                line[0] = new Vertex(organism.position, Color.Red);
                line[1] = new Vertex(new Vector2f(organism.position.X + (float)(120 * Math.Cos((organism.rotation - 30) * 0.0174)), organism.position.Y + (float)(120 * Math.Sin((organism.rotation - 30) * 0.0174))), Color.Red);
                window.Draw(line, PrimitiveType.Lines);

                line[0] = new Vertex(organism.position, Color.Red);
                line[1] = new Vertex(new Vector2f(organism.position.X + (float)(120 * Math.Cos((organism.rotation + 30) * 0.0174)), organism.position.Y + (float)(120 * Math.Sin((organism.rotation + 30) * 0.0174))), Color.Red);
                window.Draw(line, PrimitiveType.Lines);

                bufferSprite.Origin = new Vector2f(8, 8);
                bufferSprite.Color = organism.color;
                bufferSprite.Rotation = organism.rotation;
                bufferSprite.Position = organism.position;
                window.Draw(bufferSprite);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SO if you want to implement a neural network yourself the typical way is to have a layer object with a 1D array of weights going into that layer. Then you have a Network object with a 1D array of all the layers. In the network you iterate over the layers passing in the inputs and getting the output of that layer to feed into the next layer. Inside the layer you loop over the weights for that layer multiplying weights by inputs and summing it. Then the final layer output is the network output.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot in understanding how it works, would you mind showing this in psuedo-code

Comment: I'll write up an answer with it pronto :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I said in the comments you'd have a layer class with weights and a network class. There's no need to break things up smaller than that in most cases.

So for the layer class, we have N weights plus a bias:

```
class Layer
{
    double[] weights;
    int nOut, nIn;
    Layer(int inputs, int outputs)
    {
        nIn=inputs; nOut=outputs;
        weights=new double[(inputs+1)*outputs]; //Assume random weights chosen
    }

    double[] processInput(double[] in)
    {
        double[] out=new double[nOut]; //initialise all to zero
        for(int i=0; i<nOut; i++)
        {
            out[i] = weights[(i+1)*nIn] //bias always present
            for(int j=0; j<nIn; j++)
            {
                out[i] +=in[j]*weights[(i+1)*nIn+j +1] //skips bias
            }
            out[i]=activationFunction(out[i])
        }
        return out
    }
}
```

Then for the network class

```
class Network
{
    List<Layer>
    //skipping adding and setting up layers

    double[] processInput(double[] in)
    {
        double[] temp=in;
        for(Layer l:layers)
        {
            temp=layer.processInput(temp); 
            //input for next layer is output from previous
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's clear